# Is it possible to have one primary key and composite key at the same time in Entity Framework code first with data annotations?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, data-annotations, ef-fluent-api

```
public class Test
{
    [Key,DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int TestId { get; set; }

    [Column(Order = 0)]
    public string TestName { get; set; }

    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public string TestVersion { get; set; }

    public string TestRef { get; set; }
}
```

The above should result in the following SQL

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test]
(
    [TestId] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    [TestName] VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL, 
    [TestVersion] VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL,
    [TestRef] VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL,  
    CONSTRAINT [dbo_Test_PK] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([TestId] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [CK_Test_TestNameTestVersion] UNIQUE ([TestName], [TestVersion]), 
    CONSTRAINT [CK_Test_TestRef] UNIQUE ([TestRef])
)
```

`TestName` and `TestVersion` combination should be unique and `TestRef` independently should be unique.

How can I achieve this using EF fluent api?

Updated : Added screen shot of the DB for EF and separately running the above query.
[image]

dbo.Test is created using the EF and dbo.TestWithSQL is created using the query

Comment: There is no *practical* difference between unique index and unique constraint except if you need to reference it as FK from another table, in which case you need the later. However, EF does not support alternate FK keys (EF Core does), so unique index is all you can get there. Hence the @CodeNotFound answer (unfortunately currently deleted) was correct.

Comment: so does that mean having indexes or keys (as shown in above figure) solves the same purpose of not allowing user to enter duplicate values ?

Comment: In that regard, yes, they serve the same purpose.

Comment: ohh it works as expected :) , but I wonder why while running the script it creates keys !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can dot that by using `Index` attribute like this:

```
public class Test
{
    [Key,DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int TestId { get; set; }

    [Column(Order = 0),
        Index("CK_Test_TestNameTestVersion", IsUnique = true, Order = 1)]
    public string TestName { get; set; }

    [Column(Order = 1),
        Index("CK_Test_TestNameTestVersion", IsUnique = true, Order = 2)]
    public string TestVersion { get; set; }

    [Index("CK_Test_TestRef", IsUnique = true)]
    public string TestRef { get; set; }
}
```

Or you can use Fluent API like this:

```
this.Property(c => c.TestRef)
    .HasColumnAnnotation(IndexAnnotation.AnnotationName, 
        new IndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute("CK_Test_TestRef") { IsUnique = true }
    );

this.Property(c => c.TestName)
    .HasColumnAnnotation(IndexAnnotation.AnnotationName, 
        new IndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute("CK_Test_TestNameTestVersion", 1) { IsUnique = true }
    );
this.Property(c => c.TestVersion)
    .HasColumnAnnotation(IndexAnnotation.AnnotationName, 
        new IndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute("CK_Test_TestNameTestVersion", 2) { IsUnique = true }
    );
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I believe we must add the [StringLength(n)] to Index attributes. And the code works like a charm but there i one thing it creates Indexes but I want it to create key Please check  the screen shot that I added to the question.

Comment: Ah if so then it is imposible. You can only have a key or compiste key and not both in the same Entity. This is not EF restrictions but Relational Database rectrictions.

Comment: it works !!! just confirmed, was bit confused why the keys not being generated while using EF but the same gets generated when I run the SQL query.